# Are complex compound queries possible in Firebase Firestore?

Tags: database, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I am using Firebase as a backend for an app, and I need to create a matchmaking system where users are matched to the current user using a number of criteria.

Since the database can contain a huge amount of users, I would like to avoid retrieving every single user from the database and filtering it manually, to avoid loading times.

The relevant data stored in each user document includes: `date of birth` (Timestamp), `an array of user interests` (list of strings), `an array of already matched user ids` (list of strings), and the `user's gender preference` (string F or M).

It should find user data according to the following queries:

1. Date of birth must be at most 2 years lower or higher than the current user
2. The interests array must contain at least one common interest with the current user
3. The gender must match the current user's gender preference
4. The user id must not already be in the current user's already matched user ids list

After the list of matching users is retrieved, I would also like it to be sorted by the amount of common interests with the current user, so the best match shows first.

So far the only solution I have is to get 50 random users from the database, check if they match (in code), and if less than 6 matches are found, keep repeating until at least 6 matches are found.
In case no matching users are found in the entire database, then simply get 6 random users.

I am aware of the limitations that Firebase has when it comes to querying and filtering data, so I'm asking if something like this is even possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This type of relational data doesn't suit a NoSQL document database very well (especially when disqualifying results based on if you've seen them before), but lets ignore that for now.

Combining condition 1, 2 and 3 is possible. But you will need to disqualify results based on condition 4 on the side requesting the data (i.e. on the client/backend - Firestore's indexes can't handle it). This is because conditions 2 and 4 both rely on arrays of data and you are limited to querying against one at a time. As the number of user matches is likely to be low vs the number of users on the platform, condition 4 is better suited to code-based filtering. These limitations are [well documented](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/queries#array_membership).

Note: Due to the sensitive nature of a user's dating profile, a profile should only contain a user's ID and profile data (no emails or phone numbers). Furthermore, you should consider serving profiles via a regulated backend such as Cloud Functions rather than just making them client-readable directly which could lead to platform abuse.

```js
const profilesColRef = collection('profiles');

const potentialMatchesQuery = query(
  profilesColRef,
  where('dob', '>=', '1996-01-01'), // use YYYY-MM-DD format (numeric/date values can get messy with timezones if not careful)
  where('dob', '<=', '2000-01-01'),
  where('gender', '==', 'M'),
  where('interests', 'array-contains-any', userInterestArray), // supports up to 10 per query! Split into chunks of 10 and merge results for more interests
  limit(50)
);

const querySnapshot = await getDocs(potentialMatchesQuery)
const results = querySnapshot.docs
  .filter((doc) => !userPreviousMatches.includes(doc.id))
  .map((doc) => ({ id: doc.id, ...doc.data() }) // expand to basic JavaScript object

// results now contains up to 50 matches
// return results to client/use results
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for the feedback, I think I know what to do now. I'm just interested in the limitation of "array-contains-any" of having a maximum of 10 elements - so I need to split the array into chunks of size 10 and repeat the query for each chunk? Also, if I happen to have another array that I need to compare with, do I need to do that in code as well, since only one "array-contains*" clause is allowed on the query?

Comment: Yes, you will need to rerun the query for each chunk (which is why I said this type of relational data doesn't work very well with the data you are querying). Regarding the second array part you will also need to handle that in code because of the query-by-array limitations.

Comment: @samthecodingman I think it is not true that the results 50 matches (Tell me if I am wrong). By using `limit(50)` and then filter by `!userPreviousMatches.includes(doc.id)` the actual number of returning documents will vary based on the number of non-matched users contained in the initial query. Therefore, the number of returning documents would be unreliable (I could technically not even return a single document if your query happened to fetch only matched users)

Comment: @AK-dev this is a known limitation as stated in the code block: "results now contains up to 50 matches". The OP needed 6 matches and they were currently choosing 50 users from the database then filtering that down to 6, repeating until they had their 6 users. I never stated that using `limit(50)` would return 50 users, even in normal Firestore queries it returns *up to* 50 users. This is why I started my answer stating that this relational data structure is a poor fit for a NoSQL database.

Answer (score 0):

Are you using the Firestore as well with your Firebase?

There you could use queries on the firebase directly.

```
Query query = users.whereEqualTo("user_interest", "sports");
```

Or use "in"-operator like this:

```
Query query = users.whereIn("user_interest", Arrays.asList("sports", "books"));
```

You don't have to fetch all users this way.

Checkout this link for more information:
https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/queries?hl=en

Answer (score 0):

```html
getSomeData(var: string) {
 const sitesRef = collection(this.firestore, 'YOUR-COLLECTION-NAME');
 const q = query(sitesRef,
                where("site_sub_type", "==", "somesite"),
                where("state", "==", var),
                orderBy("site_id")
        );
    return collectionData(q, { idField: 'id'}) as Observable<ksa_Site[]>;
}
```

This works.  You can layer in the where clauses.  You then just call it in your component ts file.

```html
this.SiteService.getSomeData(this.var).subscribe(res => {
     this.ARRAY_OF_VALUES = res; 
     this.cd.detectChanges();
});
```

remeber you need this value
ARRAY_OF_VALUES: YOUR_DATA_STRUCTURE[] = [];